# How to show login saved in cookie in Page_load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, cookies

I need save login of my Login page in cookie for show every time when page is loaded

I have create for save login in cookie, in Button click event. but, because in the Post Back, Page_Load before button, so when page_load put cookie information in the TextBox, my cookie is empty

What can I do for resolve this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This time, Cookies["login"].Value is empty
    tbLogin.Text = Response.Cookies["login"].Value;
}

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("login", tbLogin.Text));
}
```

Comment: You want to pass login credentials back and forth with every page request? That seems like a bad idea. Why don't you investigate some of the built in authentication schemes rather than rolling your own?

Comment: Yes, I want if login is failed, user not need type again your username, can you tell me any way, please?

Comment: Interesting. Why don't you just put the login information in Session instead? Wouldn't it be easier?

Comment: Today's modern browser remember what you have typed in textbox. If i m understand you wrong then i think what you want to implement is the feature of - "Remember me" like functionality right ??

Answer (score 0):

Try using Page.IsPostBack property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        tbLogin.Text = Response.Cookies["login"].Value;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("login", tbLogin.Text));
}
```

Comment: Why when I use this method, my Login cookie is cleaned? login cookie will turn empty

Comment: May be you are doing wrong something else? I updated my code snippet to match full example. If this still doesn't work, could you fall into more details please?